# Interpreting summary function for lm model in R

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

What is the meaning of `t value` and `Pr(>|t|)` when using `summary()` function on linear regression model in R?

```
Coefficients:
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                    10.1595     1.3603   7.469 1.11e-13 ***
log(var)                        0.3422     0.1597   2.143   0.0322 *
```

Comment: See [here, last sentence of first paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis#Regression_diagnostics), and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-test#Slope_of_a_regression_line) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value).

Comment: And for standard error, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The column t value shows you the t-test associated with testing the significance of the parameter listed in the first column. For example the t value of 7.369 refers to the t-test of the (Intercept) 10.1595 divided by the standard error of that estimate 1.3603.  Pr(>|t|) gives you the p-value for that t-test (the proportion of the t distribution at that df which is greater than the absolute value of your t statistic).  1.11e-13 is scientific notation.  The asterisks following the Pr(>|t|) provide a visually accessible way of assessing whether the statistic met various $\alpha$ criterions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite grok t-test, but [wikipedia has a good article about p-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value)  - basically the p-value is the chance that the result you're seeing happened due to random variation.  Commonly a p-value of .05 or less (interpreted roughly as "there's a 5% chance or less of this happening just due to random variation") is taken to mean that the result is significant.

Comment: Because these issues have been discussed extensively on this site, I will be brief: (1) the p-value is a probability *conditional* on assuming the null hypothesis (it's not some unconditional "chance" *and it's likely contrafactual*) and (2) it is not a chance of "the result you're seeing"--which in this case is practically zero--but rather it's the chance--under the null hypothesis--that your result would fall within a "critical region" for the hypothesis test. Although this may seem like nit-picking, much confusion can arise from misinterpreting loose language.

Comment: @whuber - thank you for taking the time to put together a correct and accurate description of p-value.  I only barely grasp that myself, honestly, but was purposefully giving a "loose language" answer to help the asker get a basic idea without overwhelming him... seems to me that a lot of statistics are like that - what a statistic actually says is not so use friendly,so people give really rough approximations that are easier to digest.  I think it was in "Six Easy Pieces" that Feynman explained physics like that.  "This isn't accurate, but it's a useful approximation"

Comment: Unfortunately, loose language leads to a lot of misguided actions taken as a result of a misunderstanding.